# Atom close Git / Outline / GitHub right-hand pane on startup

Tags: panel, atom-editor

When I fire up the [Atom](https://atom.io/) text editor, it has both the left and right pane open.  Observe:

[image]

But I don't want the right pane to be open.

How can I configure Atom to have the right pane closed by default when I open a project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can uncheck the *Initial Outline Display* package setting:

[image]

If you don't know how to find this dialog, click on the package in *Settings > Packages* or use a package such as [package-settings](https://atom.io/packages/package-settings) to do so via the command palette.

Comment: I didn't realize that the "Outline" tab was the culprit.  This solution worked for me, thank you.